# Service to ping web server

Tags: php, python, c, url, ip

I have a dedicated webserver running PHP software which needs to automatically collect and update the IP's of a couple Windows and possibly Linux machines of mine which have dynamic IP's (roughly same idea as the no-ip.com client). The simplest thing to do I think is to run a service on each machine which simply pulls a unique URL from the webserver which can then lookup the client IP and match it with the URL etc.

```
    $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]
```

What's the best language/library/environment to build a client service which can make a URL request with easy access to the machine's external IP (to check for changes to the dynamic IP so as to not flood the webserver)? It need not be anything fancy, it doesn't even need to read anything from the server, it just has to make the URL request.

Besides web programming, I have some experience with Python and C and a few others. Any pointers or resources I can read up on the subject would be appreciated. Also, am I over-thinking this? Thanks

Comment: They all work just fine, just use whichever you know best.

Comment: programming language isn't a barrier, on the other hand if you had to  handle massive amount of IPs (and the complexity of your tables is low) then its better to use a non-rel database instead of MySQL. Note that if you'd decide to use MongoDB its drivers are not as good as Python's.

Comment: Hrm, I may not have been very clear. I'm not worried about the server. I'm just trying to get the clients to make a request to the webserver with a unique URL everytime they detect that their IP has changed. I found the Mechanize python library (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to make URL requests, but I'm not sure how to turn this into a Windows service. pywin32? Also after some research the clients are behind routers so I guess I have no choice but to ping some external server, might as well be mine.

Comment: If you want to write a Windows service, your best choice of language is probably C++ or C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a shell script with wget calls followed by a sleep in a loop.

wget performs http requests and it's available for windows and is already installed on all/some unix machines.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize is way overkill for making URL requests in Python. It's really really easy:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
urlopen("my://url").read()
```

The first line may vary depending on your version of Python (for instance, it's `urllib.request` in Python 3.)

There are hundreds of "What's my IP" services out there; or you could even write your own! Plug one of those into the URL read to get the IP. You'll have to poll to work out when it changes, since you can't run code on the router.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have some kind of method to do an URL request, do one each 10 minutes to this Page:

http://checkip.dyndns.org/Current%20IP%20Check.htm

wich will tell you "Current IP Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", and you only have to extract some string data.

(You only flood the whatsmyip webserver, and not your own anymore!)

Glad to Help

EGOrecords